# Content won't print from requests.get

Tags: python, python-requests

When I paste the link into the browser it pulls up the JSON content just fine but when I run it through python is does not return anything. This is what I have so far.

```
    import requests

    r = requests.get('http://api.indeed.com/ads/apisearch?publisher=publishernumber&q=java&l=austin%2C+tx&sort=&format=json&radius=&st=&jt=&start=&limit=&fromage=&filter=&latlong=1&co=us&chnl=&userip=1.2.3.4&useragent=Mozilla/%2F4.0%28Firefox%29&v=2')

    print r.content
```

Comment: You'll have to ask indeed.com why they filter on specific clients. This is not a `requests` issue. You could try to figure out (by trial and error) what headers indeed.com uses to filter by (we can't know because HTTP servers are black boxes).

Comment: I agree with @MartijnPieters, I tried an example with json and it works fine. Probably you could also check `r` value.